# behavior of tcp protocol upon receiving wrong ack number

Tags: tcp

How does tcp protocol (of an established connection) respond to a package with an ack number higher than the largest sequence number sent. That is, the other party tells that it has received bytes that the other end of the connection have not sent.

How does tcp protocol respond to that?